# Speed over VPN is 10x slower than connection to VPN or VPN<=>Destination

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, performance-tuning, iperf

I'm trying to setup VPN for my own use.
I have noticed very strange issue with speeds which I struggle to understand.

**Question:**
What is causing slow download speed from AWSFrankfurt when using VPN?

**Setup:**
[**HOME**] My ISP home connection with bandwidth 30mbps
[**VPN**]: AWS-Singapore, t2.medium, Ubuntu, l2tp ipsec.
[**AWSSingapore**]: AWS-Singapore, t2.medium, Ubuntu
[**LinodeSingapore**]:  20$mo ssd node, Ubuntu
[**AWSFrankfurt**]: AWS-Frankfurt, t2.medium, Ubuntu

Download/Upload in mbps
1) **HOME** <=> **AWSSingapore** 30mbps/30mbps
2) **VPN** <=> **AWSSingapore** 600mbps/600mbps
3) **HOME** <=> **VPN** <=> **AWSSingapore** 30mbps/30mbps

4) **HOME** <=> **LinodeSingapore** **0.1mbps**/15mbps
5) **VPN** <=> **LinodeSingapore** 30mbps/300mbps
6) **HOME** <=> **VPN** <=> **LinodeSingapore** 20mbps/10mbps

7) **HOME** <=> **AWSFrankfurt** **2mbps**/30mbps
8) **VPN** <=> **AWSFrankfurt** 60mbps/40mbps
9) **HOME** <=> **VPN** <=> **AWSFrankfurt** **5mbps**/20mbps

I started investigation because of line #4. I could barely connect with SSH.
Then VPN solved that issue for me.
But not on line #9.

How is that possible?

I'm using l2tp/ipsec only to connect HOME<=> VPN all other connections are plain\open connections.
I have root access to all severs above
All nodes have nearly zero CPU usage during tests.
I'm testing connection speed using `iperf -s` and `iperf -c IP` and downloading   file using `curl http://....` from nginx server.
Results are the consistent over time (multiple days).

Line #3 means there is no problem for VPN node to handle that much traffic in terms of CPU.

**Question:**
What is causing slow download speed from AWSFrankfurt when using VPN?